# Importing XLSX to JSON without the sheet names

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx

I'm using the following line to import an XLSX sheet into JSON in JavaScript, that is `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array`. It works fine but the sheet name is imported too as **"{ "Search Results:": [ {"**

How can I get rid of the sheet name and have the JSON simply start with "[{"? Is there a non-documented option?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution, and wanted to let you know.

Here is the original code I used:

```
var result = {};
workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var roa =XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
    if (roa.length > 0) {
        result[sheetName] = roa;
    }
});
```

And with the code below, since I'm only interested in the first sheet of the workbook, the SheetName does not appear anymore and the JSON is what I expected.

```
var result = {};
var roa=XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
   if (roa.length>0) {
       result=roa;
   };
```